# tomcat8.sh vs catalina.sh vs startup.sh

Tags: tomcat

I found the below difference:

- catalina.sh run ---> Starting tomcat in foreground.
- startup.sh ---> Starting tomcat in background while writing response 
  in log file.

I am unable to find the comparison with this command:

- tomcat8.sh start.

It also starts the tomcat service correctly but is there any difference with the other commands?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

If you read the comments in these scripts, you'll see what they are supposed to do.

- `catalina.sh` - does everything
- `startup.sh` - calls `catalina.sh start`
- `tomcat8.sh` - doesn't exist

You can start Tomcat in the foreground like this:

```
$ $CATALINA_HOME/bin/catalina.sh run
```

Or you can start it in the background like this:

```
$ $CATALINA_HOME/bin/catalina.sh start
```

There are other verbs that `catalina.sh` accepts. You can find those by running:

```
$ $CATALINA_BASE/bin/catalina.sh -h
```